# How to draw high quality text in 3D with DirectX / SharpDX

Tags: c#, text, directx, sharpdx, cleartype

My aim is to draw text onto a texture and then having that texture 
mapped onto a flat surface in 3D space.
Is it possible to have font hinting and/or ClearType under these circumstances?

It's ok to redraw the text(ure) every frame.
DirectX10/11 acceptable.

Comment: Would the text be screen aligned or in an arbitary orientation?

Comment: Arbitrary orientation